# Parse a remote (and variable) XML file into an array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, arrays

I'm a complete noob to JavaScript and jQuery (started learning yesterday), but I already find it very easy to use, so intuitive! :)

So, what I need to do is to parse an XML file (which will be spit by a remote PHP file depending on the query I send), and put it into an array that I can later use to draw charts, etc.

The trick here is that the XML file will have a different structure and categories depending on the query, so I need a kind of "universal" parser.

The only thing I can control is that all base items will be called "item", but the categories inside each item will change depending on the query, which will be modified by the user at runtime.

The structure will always look like this:

```
<results>
 <item>
  <variable1>value1</variable1>
  <variable2>value2</variable2>
  <variable3>value3</variable3>
  <variable4>value4</variable4>
  <variable5>value5</variable5>
 </item>
 <item>
  <variable1>value6</variable1>
  <variable2>value7</variable2>
  <variable3>value8</variable3>
  <variable4>value9</variable4>
  <variable5>value10</variable5>
 </item>
</results>
```

And I would like to have an array like this:

```
results[0].variable1 = value1
results[0].variable2 = value2
results[0].variable3 = value3
results[0].variable4 = value4
results[0].variable5 = value5

results[1].variable1 = value6
results[1].variable2 = value7
results[1].variable3 = value8
results[1].variable4 = value9
results[1].variable5 = value10
```

But as I said, I can only guarantee the "item" name. The names of the variables will be variable in each case.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My suggestion would be to check the documentation ;) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var arr={};// Object if you want an array then use=> var arr=[];
$('item').each(function(index,value){
    var data={};
    $(this).find('*').each(function(i,v){
      data[$(this).prop('tagName')]=$(this).text();
    });
    arr[index]=data;
})
console.log(arr);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XT97Y/1/)

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. I've fiddled with it and I managed to get it working. However, I'm not facing a VERY strange issue: depending on how "long" the query is, the ajax function will succeed or not. Specifically, if the query has AT LEAST 14 elements, it WILL work. But less than that, the succeed function isn't triggered?? I've looked at the XML generated by the PHP script and it's IDENTICAL in all cases except for the number of elements. All I can think of is the time it takes for the PHP script to respond... any idea why it might not work when the time is less than around 10 seconds??

Comment: Some more insight into the error... looking at chrome Console tab, it seems to throw a 500 Internal Server error.

However, as I pointed out, the XML file is identical to the working one... the only difference is in the number of elements/time it takes to run... which in this case is LOWER than before. Any ideas??